# How to edit form entry in a modal

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I have a `form` that is accessed via a `modal` as described in the below code.

I am able to click on `new-lesson-plan-modal` and use the generated form to input a new post entry, which will then be displayed back on the `html`.

My question is, how do I edit the post entries via `edit-lesson-plan-modal`? The buttons have been created. But i'm not sure how to hook up the button to the `modal`, such that it will retrieve the records for the relevant post entry, to be edited on the form.

Any ideas?

**Views.py**

```
def home(request, pk=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Adding lesson plans
        if 'update_lesson_plan' in request.POST:
            lesson_plan_page_data = LessonPlans.objects.all()
            edited_lp = NewLessonPlansForm(request.POST)
            if edited_lp.is_valid():
                edited_lp.save()

        else:  # get
            # Lesson Plans Section
            lesson_plan_page_data = LessonPlans.objects.all()
            edited_lp = NewLessonPlansForm()

        args = {
            'lesson_plans': lesson_plan_page_data,
            'edited_lp': edited_lp,
        }
        return render(request, 'static/html/home.html', args)
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table" id="id_view_lesson_plan">
        <caption><small>Lesson Plans</small></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Level</th>
                <th scope="col">Lesson</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add new Lesson Plan">
                        <button type="button" class="btn new-lesson-plan-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lesson-plan-modal">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for lp in lesson_plans %}
                <tr>
                   <td>{{ lp.level }}</td>
                   <td>{{ lp.lesson }}</td>
                   <td>{{ lp.description }}</td>
                   <td>
                      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Lesson Plan" >
                          <button type="button" class="btn edit-lesson-plan-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
                              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                          </button>
                      </span>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Modal section**

```
<!-- Modal for new_lesson_plans-->
<div class="modal fade" id="lesson-plan-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">New Lesson Plan</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="lesson-update-section" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row align-center was-validated">
                        <!-- New Lesson Plan Form -->
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">{{ edited_lp.level }}</div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">{{ edited_lp.lesson }}</div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">{{ edited_lp.description }}</div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="update_lesson_plan" class="btn btn-success" name="update_lesson_plan">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But could you please explain more? I don't quite follow.

Comment: This is not related to django. It's more of a JS/HTML related question. Hint: read about [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: I went through the link you posted. So I can do something like `data-value={{ lp.pk }}` to store the `pk` value? But how can this be fed back to `django` to populate the `modal` form? Or can this only be access via `javascript`?

Comment: You don't need to pass anything back to django. You can read the values from data attributes and fill the inputs -- all using JavaScript. In fact, you don't even need data attributes, you can just read the text inside `td` tags and populate the inputs. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the workflow:

1. User clicks the *Edit* button.
2. You monitor the click event from javascript to identify which button was clicked.
3. Then you find its parent row (`<tr>`) element.
4. Then you find children columns (`<td>`) of the row.
5. Then you find the data from those elements.
6. Then you populate the modal inputs.

Here's an example with simplified code.

Table:

```
<!-- add an id to the row to identify it later -->
<tr id="lesson-{{ lp.pk }}">

    <!-- add a class to the column to identify it later -->
    <td class="lesson-level">{{ lp.level }}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="edit-lesson-plan-modal" data-row="#lesson-{{ lp.pk }}"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Modal:

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
    ...
    <!-- add an id to the input fields to identify it later -->
    <input type="text" id="lesson-level-edit-input">
</div>
...
```

Javascript:

```
$('.edit-lesson-plan-modal').on('click', function() {
    // get the parent row's id
    var rowId = $(this).attr('data-row');

    // get the parent row element
    var row = $(rowId);

    // get the lp.level data
    // below `.lesson-level` is the class of the column
    var lessonLevel = row.children('.lesson-level')[0].innerText();

    // populate the input field
    // below `#lesson-level-edit-input` is the id of the input
    $('#lesson-level-edit-input').val(lessonLevel);

    // open the modal
    $('#lesson-plan-modal').show();
});
```